# Nginx UDP load balance transparent proxy source IP

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, udp

I've setup an nginx load balancer on AWS to forward UDP packets to a range of radius servers (UDP:1812). I'm struggling to get the transparent mode working - `proxy_bind...` properly. I need the source IP!

With the following configuration, the packets are not forwarded to the servers (I've checked using tcpdump on the upstream server). I can see the packets being received in the logs and via tcpdump on the nginx server.

```
user root;
worker_processes 1;
daemon off;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

stream {

    upstream auth_servers {
        server radius.xxx:1812;
    }

    server {
        listen 1812 udp;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/radius.log debug;

        proxy_responses 0;
        proxy_bind $remote_addr transparent;
        proxy_pass auth_servers;
    }
}
```

So I've tried to enable ipv4 forwarding:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Still nothing hitting the upstream.

So, I tried adding the following IPTABLES rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And boom! I see traffic on the upstream servers.... But the source IP is that of the nginx server (I guess because of the darn MASQUERADE rule).

So, I tried locally with a couple o' virtualbox images. I was able to get the forwarding to work if I bound the listener to the IP of the machine.

In this case, I've tried doing so with the VPC IP - totally unsuccessful.

Have tried three distributions - literally everything now...

I'm looking for a way to get the actual source IP.

Comment: I suspect there are other potential problems with your approach to this issue, but any time an EC2 instance is mangling packets, you have to [disable the IP Source/Dest Check](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck) on the instance to prevent the network from discarding the packets as nonsense.

Comment: Thanks, that got traffic to the upstreams. I can see the response being sent from the upstream back to the client. We've routed this through the load balancer as per https://www.nginx.com/blog/ip-transparency-direct-server-return-nginx-plus-transparent-proxy/. Have also created a custom firewall rule etc. I can see the reply being sent back to the client but never see this arrive ON the client. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

For those who still wants an answer for this use:

```js
server {
  proxy_bind   $remote_addr:$remote_port transparent;
}
```